# How do I use parameters of parent class method with the same method name?

Tags: php, codeigniter

The title is a bit confusing, I know, but it's the best I could do.  =P

Hopefully, someone will be able to help.

I'm using CodeIgniter and I have a method in a base class that has multiple parameters:

```
class MY_Base extends CI_Model {

    function some_function($param1, $param2 ... $param8) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

What I want to do is basically this, in a child class:

```
class Child extends MY_Base {

    function some_function($param1, $param2 ... $param8) {
        parent::some_function($param1, $param2 ... $param8);
        // call a methods found in this class only
        $this->some_method();
    }

    function some_method() {
        // do more stuff
    }
}
```

I can't touch the base classes so I have to extend from it. Problem is, There are just too many parameters. And this happens in different methods as well and sometimes I forget one which makes the code fail.

So I was wondering, if there's a way to write it like this:

```
function some_function(__PARAMETERS__) {
    parent::some_function(__PARAMETERS__)
}
```

I seem to vaguely recall that this is possible but I can't find it in Google. Probably because I'm searching the wrong keywords.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
And then, of course, I find `func_get_args()` after posting this question. 
This seems to do what I want, but I'll leave this question up for better ideas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function some_function($a, $b, $c) {
    call_user_func_array('parent::some_function', func_get_args());
}
```

**WARNING**: PHP >= 5.3

or even:

```
function some_function($a, $b, $c) {
    call_user_func_array('parent::' . __FUNCTION__, func_get_args());
}
```

Comment: Wont this just pass an array to the parent function when it needs a bunch of different arguments?

Comment: @Galen: that's the difference between `call_user_func` and `call_user_func_array`. The latter accepts an array and passes its elements as a separated parameters

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks, I will use this.

Answer (score 8):

For PHP >=7.0 I use:

```
parent::{__FUNCTION__}(...func_get_args())
```

Comment: This is by far the easiest method! You can even leave out the arguments in the function declaration. For example: `public function __construct() { parent::__construct(...func_get_args()); }`

Comment: Note that this doesn't work if you're overriding an argument default in the signature of the child constructor. The `func_get_args()` function does not account for default values of arguments not passed. So, for example if the parent constructor is `public function __construct($something = false) {}` and the child changes that default value like so: `public function __construct($something = true) { parent::__construct(...func_get_args()); }`, the value of `$something` in the parent will still be `false` if no argument is passed to the child constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the following `callParent()` method in your most parent class

```
/**
 * Calls the parent class's same function, passing same arguments.
 * This is similar to ExtJs's callParent() function, except that agruments are 
 * FORCED to be passed (in extjs, if you call this.callParent() - no arguments would be passed,
 * unless you use this.callParent(arguments) expression instead)
 */
function callParent() {

    // Get call info from backtrace
    $call = array_pop(array_slice(debug_backtrace(), 1, 1));

    // Make the call
    call_user_func_array(get_parent_class($call['class']) . '::' . $call['function'], $call['args']);
}
```

So, in your child classes methods, if you want to call parent method, you can just use

```
$this->callParent();
```

instead of

```
call_user_func_array('parent::' . __FUNCTION__, func_get_args());
```

expression

Answer (score 0):

You can call it with [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) function.

Eg:

```
 <?php
 function some_function($var1, $var2, $var3)
 {
    call_user_func_array('parent::'.__METHOD__, func_get_args());
 }
 ?>
```